# Why am I getting NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, spyder

I'm using spyder and have written the following class:

```
class Ray:

    def __init__(self, r, p, k):

        if r.shape == (3,):
            self.r = r
        if p.shape == (3,):
            self.p = p
        if k.shape == (3,):
            self.k = k

r = array(range(3))
p = array(range(3))
k = array(range(3))
```

It is stored in /home/user/workspace/spyder/project and the console working directory is that one. In the console I can run an array(range(3)) and it returns an array with values 0,1,2. However when doing

```
import ray
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ray.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Ray:
  File "ray.py", line 20, in ray
    r = array(range(3));
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

**EDIT:**

by default spyder has the following behaviour, don't really understand why array() works by default I thought it was only part of numpy.

```
import numpy as np  # NumPy (multidimensional arrays, linear algebra, ...)
import scipy as sp  # SciPy (signal and image processing library)

import matplotlib as mpl         # Matplotlib (2D/3D plotting library)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Matplotlib's pyplot: MATLAB-like syntax
from mayavi import mlab          # 3D plotting functions
from pylab import *              # Matplotlib's pylab interface
ion()                            # Turned on Matplotlib's interactive mode

Within Spyder, this intepreter also provides:
    * special commands (e.g. %ls, %pwd, %clear)
    * system commands, i.e. all commands starting with '!' are subprocessed
      (e.g. !dir on Windows or !ls on Linux, and so on)
```

Comment: You miss some imports then.

Comment: Side note: in order to follow PEP 8, I started your class name with an uppercase letter, I put spaces between the `__init__()` arguments. I also removed unnecessary ending ";" and made `Ray` a new-style class. (Well, that was before you edited it again. You might want to consider putting back my improvements.)

Comment: The comment for `from pylab import *` is wrong: it does `from numpy import *` internally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `from numpy import array`.

This is done for you by the Spyder console. But in a program, you must do the necessary imports; the advantage is that your program can be run by people who do not have Spyder, for instance.

I am not sure of what Spyder imports for you by default. `array` might be imported through `from pylab import *` or equivalently through `from numpy import *`. If you want to directly copy code from the Spyder console to a program, you might need `from numpy import *` or even `from pylab import *`. It is [officially not recommended to do this in a program](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules), though, as this pollutes the program's namespace; doing `import numpy as np` and then `np.array(…)` is customary.

Comment: edited the answer to show what spyder imports by default. What I'm confused though is since spyder has already imported numpy why does it not work? Also, it doesn't make a difference if I use np.array instead of array

Comment: After doing `import numpy`, you access the `array()` function with `numpy.array()`, no `array()`.  After doing  `from pylab import *`, you have a new, imported `array()` which is exactly the same as NumPy's (`array == numpy.array` returns `True`).

Comment: Ok I'm confused. If I add `import numpy as np` at any point in the script it seems to be fine. If I open a python interpreter and run `import numpy as np` and then copy paste the code it works fine. However, if I `import numpy as np` and then `from ray import *` it returns an error?

Comment: ok I think i figured stuff out.. basically things need to be imported within each module... if I'm wrong correct me..

Comment: Yeah, each module has its own namespace. So, if you want `array` to be defined in a module, you need to define it *inside the module* (this can be done with `from numpy import array`, for instance, or by using `numpy.array()` after `import numpy`). The advantage of this "import all necessary modules" approach is that it makes each module independent (the same module can be used in many different projects, without having to think about whether other parts of the project imported the required objects).